# Section will be overlapped by header when come from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem. What I want is when the user clicks in the navigation bar on "Contact" it will link to the contact page. This is a single page. When you are on contact and then clicking at the bottom of the page on, for example "Over ons" it should be redirect to the homepage (single page) and stop at that section. This works, but when you come from another page, the current section is overlapped by the header.

The jQuery code will not use the offset of the header, only when you are navigation inside the `index.html`.

Is there a way to fix the issue, so the section will not be overlapped by the header?

Live example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqxxQd

jQuery code:

```
// An offset to push the content down from the top
    var offset = $('#header').outerHeight();

    $('#primary-navwrapper li:not(.prev-page, .next-page), .list-of-links li').find('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();


        $('#primary-navwrapper li a').removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");

        var anchorId = $(this).attr("href");
        var target = $(anchorId).offset().top - offset;         


        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = anchorId;        
        });

    });



    function setActiveListElements(event){
        // Get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('#primary-navwrapper li a[href^="#"]').each(function() { 
            var anchorId = $(this);
            var target = $(anchorId.attr("href"));

            var offsetTop = target.position().top - offset;

            if (target.length > 0) {

                if (target.position().top - offset <= windowPos && (target.position().top + target.height() + offset ) > windowPos) {

                    $('#primary-navwrapper li a').removeClass("current");
                    anchorId.addClass("current");
                }
            }

        });

    }

$(window).scroll(function() {
        setActiveListElements();
        //updateLocationHash();
    });
```

Comment: We can't go to the "Contact" page from your Code Pen.

Comment: This is the codepen of the contact page http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPrabw . It works for me, when you click on `contact` inside the top navigation. If it is not working let me know! @krillgar

Comment: @Caspert There is no top navigation in that example.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see the Code Pen open in the lower section, and had to move the separator to see down to the page again. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Something I don't know how to fix in Codepen.

Comment: Please put your relevant code in your question. If codepen disappears of the internet then your question becomes useless to other people with a potential same issue.

Comment: @Caspert I've noticed. I would normally say that you need to add your CSS and HTML too, but I just tried putting that into an answer for it to turn around and say "You can only have 30000 characters, you currently have 41812" _\*facepalm\*_

Comment: Yes it's a lot of code to get in the question and it's basically something inside jQuery. It ignore the function `var offsetTop = target.position().top - offset;` @JamieBarker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to scroll down to each section needs to be placed in it's own function called something sensible like `FireActiveElement`. Give it one parameter that sends through your `anchorId` string. Your click listener then needs to call that function.

So you have a function similar to:

```
function FireActiveElement(anchorId) {
    var target = $(anchorId).offset().top - offset;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = anchorId;
    });
}
```

Then, what you can do is something like this:

```
function CheckHash() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        FireActiveElement(window.location.hash);
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to add that function as a callback to your body fade in:

```
$('body').fadeIn(500, CheckHash);
```

Difficult to test this works myself, but hope that helps you.

P.S.

If you need to have more things that are fired upon page load, you might want to change the `fadeIn` slightly to something like:

```
$('body').fadeIn(500, function() {
    CheckHash();
    // Examples:
    SomeOtherFunction();
    FireMeOnPageLoad();
});
```

Comment: No problem! I appreciate your answer :) And should I call `FireActiveElement` inside my click function?

Comment: @Caspert Yes :) - "_Your click listener then needs to call that function._"

Comment: @Caspert Just realised there was a mistake in CheckHash function so I have updated.

Comment: @Caspert You're not sending through the `anchorID` on your click function. The only code you needed to remove in your click function was the code that's been put in the `FireActiveElement` function. You'll then just need to do `FireActiveElement(anchorID);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77328/discussion-between-jamie-barker-and-caspert).